# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning despite multiple Error checks

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-mysql, request-promise

I recently have been developing a web app with NODEJS. I have a db model that takes care of all crud operations. Sample DB model

```js
    getDeviceList: function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM `devices`";
            db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`FAILED: ${err}`);
                    reject(err);
                } else resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }
```

And I access this function in DB module like

```js
router.get("/inventory/devices", checkAuth, function (req, res, next) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.getDeviceList().then(function (result) {
            resolve(res.status(200).json(result));
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(`FAILED: ${err}`);
            reject(res.status(200).json(err));
        });
    });
});
```

Sometimes when I close the DataBase; I get **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning** but In my eyes I am handling all the promises. What is the best way of handling promises and is my method of **retrun promise** correct?
My DB connection block is in `app.js`

```js
var connection = db.connectDB().then(function (connect) {}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(`FAILED: ${err}`);
});
```

and my `connectDB()` is

```js
function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            db = mysql.createPool({
                host: "localhost",
                port: 3306,
                user: "migration",
                password: "iub5015",
                database: "migration"
            });
            db.getConnection(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`FAILED: ${err}`);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Connected");
                    resolve(db);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last statement in your catch block,

```
reject(res.status(200).json(err));
```

means that the returned promise is in rejected state. ie the Promise returned by `router.get("/inventory/devices", checkAuth, function (req, res, next)` is in rejected state and you have missed to catch that. (or express does not catch that as it seems in your case)

This is why you are getting this **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning**.

> What is the best way of handling promises and is my method of retrun
>   promise correct?

Well, in my experience it depends. In some scenarios you may want to propagate error by rejecting Promise, or in some case you may just want to handle it some way and return something as resolved value. In your case you may have to look into express docs to figure out how you need to implement promises within your middleware.

```
router.get("/inventory/devices", checkAuth, function (req, res, next) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.getDeviceList().then(function (result) {
            resolve(res.status(200).json(result));
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(`FAILED: ${err}`);
            // This will not give UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning 
            resolve(res.status(500).json(err));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: but if in both cases I resolve this; my front end's try catch will not actually work. Is that correct?

Comment: You should not mix frontend backend stuff, treat them as two different entities

Comment: For the frontend, I guess ```resolve(res.status(500).json(err))``` will still be regarded as a error since the http error code in response will be 500.

Comment: so, in your design i will depend on status codes. I was sending 200 no matter what.

Comment: Its basically the HTTP protocol that govern these rules. ```res.status(2xx)``` will send a http status code of 2xx, ie success and ```res.send(4xx)``` or ```res.send(5xx)``` will send status code in the series 4xx and 5xx that will be treated as errors. Do have a look into these MDN docs

Comment: Apologies I am aware of the codes, I was just thinking if it would catch when I reject with a response.

Comment: Maybe my connection block throws the error but It seems I have handled the errors there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205639/discussion-between-sakib11-and-nmxl).

Answer (score -1):

```
    router.get("/inventory/devices", checkAuth, function (req, res, next) {
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.getDeviceList().then(function (result) {
            resolve(result);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(`FAILED: ${err}`);
            reject(err);
        });
    }).then(r => {
        res.status(200).json(r)
     }).catch(er => {
       res.status(400).json(er)
     })
});
```

Comment: what is the second catch catching? the new promise?

Comment: Add a little context if possible please.

Comment: In the router, you didn't handle this promise.

Comment: How should we handle it? If I use a db model; should the db model return new promises? and if I use a router; should routers return new promises?

Comment: so each promise has its own then and catch?

Comment: yes.
Use promise where it requires. In your router, I think the promise is required here.

Comment: I still get that error. How should I construct the db connection model. Like should it return a promise? or should it be a new promise?

Comment: Instead of promise you can use a callback function.

Comment: I would like to understand promises a bit more if that is okay with you. I want to learn not just fix the error.

Comment: Your promise is fine, each promise has to be it's own then and catch. I think your error handling is not working in the router.

Comment: yeah. But how should I handle it? In your answer, you asked me to wrap then catch for a new promise? What are we catching? like if my router is a promise and it rejects; then that is it right? why would I want to catch that?. Should routers even be a promise?